# Google Test でテストごとにパラメーターを渡すには？

Tags: c++11, テスト

Google Testでテストごとにパラメーターを渡すには？

Google Test初心者です。
パラメーターを受け取る複数種類のテストに共通の初期化処理を書きたいです。イメージとしては以下のような機能がほしいです。

```
class Fixture200 : public   ::testing::Test {
public:
    static void SetUpTestCase() {
        //　テストケース共通の初期化処理
    }
    static void TearDownTestCase() {
        // テストケース共通のターム処理
    }
    virtual void SetUp() {
　　　　// テストごとの初期化処理
    }
    virtual void TearDown() {
       // テストごとのターム処理
    }
};

TEST_F(Fixture200, Test01) {
    GetParam(); // パラメーター受け取り。
}
TEST_F(Fixture200, Test02) {
    GetParam(); // パラメーター受け取り。Test01とは全く違う型のパラメーター。
}
```

testing::TestWithParamを使うとテストケースごとにしかパラメーターを扱えないので、目的から少しそれます。

最終的にやりたいことは複数のテストが共通の初期化処理をもっていて、その共通の初期化処理は一度だけ実行される。さらにそのテストケースに属するテストはそれぞれ別のパラメーターを食うという動作を実現したいです。

回答よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 10年近く前の質問/7年前の回答ですが何か参考になるかも。[Google Test: Is there a way to combine a test which is both type parameterized and value parameterized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8507385/9014308) そのリンクにこんな記事も。[Advanced use of googletest's parameterization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41987295/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。